# How to set data-id attribute

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the data-id and/or value of a span from my js file after a click event.

```
<span id="test"></span>
```

my sudo code js file

```
nextLink: function(event) {
    $('#test').val = 3;
    $('#test').data('id') = 'Next';
},
```

Comment: whats your question? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @what it has to do with backbone.js ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try setting it as an attribute..

```
 $('#test').attr('data-id' , 'Next');   // JQuery
```

You can also try the `setAttribute()` ..

```
var d = document.getElementById("test");  //   Javascript
d.setAttribute('data-id' , 'Next');       //
```

Using this approach will reflect the new attribute in the DOM

In your code
You are trying to set the attribute which is not present .. So you need to add the attribute first to add that ..

Answer (score 4):

You probably need this:

```
$('#test').data('id', 'Next');
```

Comment: But setting it this way the attribute won't be reflected in the DOM

Comment: @Sushanth--, yes but you'll be able to get value by `var id = $('#test').data('id')`. It depends on your needs if you wish an attribute or just save data.